# How to save the userID with the session cookie

Tags: asp.net, authentication

When the user checks on "Log me automatically" in the login page, I have a problem that the user is logged-in on my asp.net application but the login info has not been read from database.

In the normal case (manual login) when the user attemps to login, if the login operation has been succeeded then the user info (id, privileges) is read and is saved in a session variable.

The question is: How to save the userID with the session cookie and how to login in the database when auto login.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I suspect you're using the login control but implementing your own code to authenticate the user. To make life really easy, have a look at [How To: Use Membership in ASP.NET 2.0](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff648345.aspx) which will automate the "log me in automatically" feature (and many more).

If you're doing this another way, it would help to provide some sample code.

Comment: Actually I'm using Oracle database, and I haven't created my own membership provider. can't I implement this manually ?

Comment: Take a look at the Oracle Providers for ASP.NET: http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/topics/dotnet/index-087367.html Of course you can always implement the whole thing yourself manually but it's a whole lot more work. It means you need to code everything from account creation to password reminders to password salting and hashing.